# How to change the color of the background in a jFrame

Tags: java

I am trying to make a planner and want to change the background of my JFrame.
I have already tried `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.);` but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code for the frame portion

```
`public Planner(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    main = new JPanel();
    menu = new Menu(this);
    frame.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
    frame.add(main);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menu);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Icon.png"));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Myva");

    JLabel loading = new JLabel();
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
    pane.showMessageDialog( null, "Hi. ");
    name = pane.showInputDialog("What is your name:");

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, then you could call [`JFrame.setBackground(Color)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29) like

```
frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

If you want to change the color in a more visible manner, you can make it on a `JPanel`. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(640, 480);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

which will give you a very `BLUE` window.

Comment: Thanks for the help but when i try to insert that code into my code it doesn't change it at all.

Comment: @fariswheel I think you actually want do it with a `JPanel`. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of your JFrame, use the following code:

```
frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

(Color doesn't have to be blue, I just used it as an example)